# "Expression: list iterators incompatible" happening randomly during iteration through a list

Tags: c++, list, iterator, std

I have been trying to use std::list, however my work has been sabotaged by following error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP120D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list
Line: 289

Expression: list iterators incompatible

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

I have searched a little (a few hours in fact), yet nothing has solved my problem.
Error shows itself in following function:

```
void Plane::createFrame(){
    for( int i = 0; i < 400; i++ ){
        frame[i] = '_';
    }
    for (std::list<Unit>::iterator iterator = units_container.begin();
        iterator != units_container.end(); ++iterator) {

        iterator->draw(frame, 20);
    }
}
```

Where draw function looks like this:

```
void Unit::draw( char(&world)[400], int width ){
    world[ position ] = avatar;     
}
```

Another interesting thing is thing is that I managed to "contain" this error:

```
void Plane::createFrame(){
    for( int i = 0; i < 400; i++ ){
        frame[i] = '_';
    }
    for (std::list<Unit>::iterator iterator = units_container.begin();
        iterator != units_container.end(); ++iterator) {

        if( iterator->getPosition() < 0 ||
            iterator->getPosition() > 399 ){
            break;
        }
        iterator->draw(frame, 20);
    }
}
```

Changed `createFrame()` seems immune to previous error.

If I change my code same error my occur in different places (change is necessary, though. Right now it is always `createFrame()` that shows error). It always show within almost the same `for` maybe with different function being invoked.

`createFrame()` is being invoked in a loop. Error usually happens after 100 lap. Changed `createFrame()` uses `break;` randomly, however error never shows.

There are no other threads that could access list.

I'm using `erase()` but error doesn't seem connected in any way.

I hope I didn't miss anything obvious, but now I can't really be sure.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looks like you are writing out of bounds to the `world` array. And the checks you added prevent that. But if you fixed the error yourself, then what is your question?

Comment: A complete example would help. I think that somewhere in your code, you try to use iterators from two different list objects.

Comment: @interjay I have solved effects, but I don't know underlying cause. This is what bothers me. I'm sorry I didn't make this clearer. It seems the darkest place is beneath the lamp. It doesn't solve all my concerns though. But now I have to do some checking before making any more conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array which is passed to `Unit::draw` as `char(&world)[400]`, and you are writing into index `position` of that array.

If `position` is not between 0 and 399, this will result in undefined behavior. This can cause various symptoms: your code may crash, it may work incorrectly, or it may display seemingly unrelated error messages such as the one you are getting about iterators.

When you added the check that `position` is between 0 and 399, the error stopped happening here. You say that it now happens elsewhere, so you should check if there is any out-of-bounds array access there (or any other kind of undefined behavior). It may be best to ensure that `position` doesn't get assigned an invalid value in the first place.

Comment: I have checked, and it seems to be right (45 000 laps). It's quite an awkward error, and I feel stupid now. There was one possibility of passing wrong argument because I forgotten to add
 "-1" in "if (new_position > map_size - 1)"
Fact that it was quite far away in my code didn't help. Debugger message seems kind of weird though. Anyway, thank You very much, it was incredibly helpful.